# Battery Runtime Remaining Expression in Zabbix

Tags: server, triggers, runtime, zabbix, battery

I'm using this expression in a trigger in Zabbix to shutdown a server when the battery runtime remaining is less than 15 minutes:

*last(/xxxx UPS 3000 SNMP/battery.runtime_remaining[upsAdvBatteryRunTimeRemaining])<15*

This is not working well anf the server keeps shutting down when the baterry runtime remaining is above 15 minutes. Is the script correct? How can I solve this?

I expect to shut down the server when the battery runtime remaining is less than 15 minutes.